# Как использовать SaveFileDialog в данном случае?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на button1 вылезал диалог (`static SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();`), где пользователь может сохранить папку в определённое место, но у меня вылезает ошибка

```
IDE1007: Имя "sfd.Title" не существует в текущем контексте.
```

И я не могу с этим разобраться. Также происходит и с другими похожими переменными.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GuiFolderCreator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    class TheProgram
        {
       // Здесь ошибка
            static SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Title = "Сохранить папку";
            sfd.Filter = "Папка";
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(sfd.FileName);

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (MessageBox.Show("Папка уже существует. Вы хотите удалить её?", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        Directory.Delete(path, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `static SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Title = "Сохранить папку", Filter = "Папка" };`

Comment: Не создавайте классы внутри классов, это вас только больше запутает. Располагайте классы рядом, а не один в другом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нельзя делать FileDialog не локальной переменной(вероятно и SaveFileDialog). 2) Используй код:

```
using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog())
{
    ofd.Filter = "folder filter |.";
    ofd.FilterIndex = 1;
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       string path = ofd.FileName + "//" + newFolderName;
       Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }
}
```